# MediaPlayer seekTo random duration

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a `MediaPlayer` and i stream an MP3 file from a link i want the music to be randomize based on the MP3's duration.

> I have tried using the `Random` class and `getDuration()` from `MediaPlayer` and `seekTo()` but failed maybe because of buffering issue.
>
> This below code just `reset()` the file because i have failed getting it to a random duration. **Please help me out**

```
try {
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, uri);
      mediaPlayer.prepare();
      mediaPlayer.start();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: getDuration returns the duration of the track or whatever sound is in the mp3 file. You are probably seeking to position which is out of range. You can only seek to 0 - total duration (returned by getDuration()).

Comment: i know, that is why i am asking how to create a random integer based on the total duration without the negative randoms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for random position:

```
randomPosition = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, mediaPlayer.getDuartion() + 1);
```

Then seek:

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(randomPosition);
```